# Error message when modal is empty

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, checkbox, label

I have a couple of modal popups on my page that hold checkboxes. The checkboxes are different items that can be added to a specific product. Some products, however, have all of one type of item assigned to them. I need a way to show a message in the modal when the modal is empty.

I have tried using a Label inside the modal that says "All features are currently associated with this product." But the label leaves a space in the modal when it's visibility is set to hidden and that was annoying so I ditched that idea.

What is a good way to have a hidden message that shows up when the modal is empty?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="FeatureButton" runat="server">Feature</asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:Panel ID="FeaturePanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup"
  Style="display:none">
     <div class="PopupHeader">Add a Feature</div>
       <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbxAddFeature" runat="server" 
       DataSourceID="dsNewFeatures" DataTextField="FeatureTitle"
       DataValueField="FeatureID"></asp:CheckBoxList>
       **<asp:Label ID="FeatureError" runat="server" 
       Text="All features are currently associated to this product." 
       Display="none"></asp:Label>**
         <asp:Button ID="SubmitFeatures" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
         <asp:Button ID="CancelSubmitFeatures" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
   </asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="FeatureModal" runat="server" 
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="CancelSubmitFeatures"
DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" 
PopupControlID="FeaturePanel" TargetControlID="FeatureButton">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>   


Protected Sub SubmitFeatures_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles SubmitFeatures.Click
FeatureModal.Hide()
For Each feature As ListItem In cbxAddFeature.Items
**FeatureError.Visible = False**
If feature.Selected Then
'SQL INSERT: Marketing Table
Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (@ProductID, 3, 'Feature', @MarketingData)"

Using cn As New   SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID.Value))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MarketingData", feature.Value))

cn.Open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
End If
**If (dsNewFeatures) == DBNull.Value Then
  FeatureError.Visible = True
End If**
 Next
 Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsNewFeatures" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT f.FeatureID, f.FeatureTitle 
    FROM Feature f LEFT JOIN Category c ON c.CategoryID = f.CategoryID 
    WHERE f.CategoryID IN 
    (SELECT CategoryID FROM CategoryLink 
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID) AND f.FeatureID NOT IN 
    (SELECT m.MarketingData FROM Marketing m 
    WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 3 AND m.ProductID = @ProductID) 
    ORDER BY f.FeatureTitle">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="id" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CategoryID" QueryStringField="id" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

All **** items are pieces of the label, the If, End If statement doesn't work, does anyone know how I can change that to get it to find an empty modal for the error message?

[image]

This is what it looks like now, notice the label showing. I don't know why it won't go away! [image]

**EDIT 9/29/11**

```
Protected Sub dsNewFeatures_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles dsNewFeatures.Selected
    If FeatureError.Text = String.Format("rows count: {0}", e.AffectedRows) Then
        FeatureError.Visible = True
    Else
        FeatureError.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

It almost works! The label is not visible just based off of this code, but I can't get it to unhide when I empty the modal

Comment: Simply adding "Display = none" to the asp:label tag is not going to do the trick of removing the space. The white space exists because asp.net's default behavior of hiding controls will still leave space for them in the rendered document flow.  To remedy this, you could try changing **FeatureError.Visible = False** in your For Each loop to **FeatureError.Attributes.Add("Style", "Display:None;")**.  That styling should remove it from the document flow.  Here's a link describing what I am trying to explain in more detail.  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: I tried the attribute code and the space still showed up. I don't know why it's there, but I will just have to get used to it being there since I can't get it to go away hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `it's visibility is set to hidden` you refer to the CSS visibility property? If so, try using `display:none` instead and that should fix the spacing issue that you dislike.

If that doesn't do it (I think it will), simply set the Visible property of the label to false in code behind when you trigger the event that pops up the dialog. I believe ASP.NET doesn't render elements when the Visible property is false so this definitely should work.

What I mean is this:

```
annoyingLabel.Visisble=False
```

You can toggle the Visible property accordingly depending on whether you need to display the message or not.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

```
How about this?

Dim showNextTime As Boolean = False
If feature.Selected Then
  '' your code here
Else 
   showNextTime =True 
End If

FeatureError.Visible = showNextTime
```

Since you are iterating through all items and checking whether they are selected or not all you need to do is set a flag that will become true the moment one of the items is not selected (meaning, there will be at least one item left to be added).

If there are no items to go through, then by default FeatureError.Visible should be false.

Does that work for you?

**UPDATE 2**

```
Dim showNextTime As Boolean = False
If feature.Selected Then
  '' your code here
Else 
   showNextTime =True 
End If
' Add this condition to make it visible if Items.Count==0 
FeatureError.Visible = (showNextTime Or cbxAddFeature.Items.Count==0)
```

**UPDATE 3** Now try this:

Add an OnCLick event to your FeatureButton as so:

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="FeatureButton_Click" ID="FeatureButton" runat="server">Feature</asp:LinkButton>
```

And on your code Behind:

```
  Sub FeatureButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
     FeatureError.Visible = (cbxAddFeature.Items.Count=0)
  End Sub
```

We will make this work.

**UPDATE 4:**
Change your OnSelected code to this (I don't know why were you comparing text):

```
Protected Sub dsNewFeatures_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles dsNewFeatures.Selected
    If  e.AffectedRows=0 Then
        FeatureError.Visible = True
        FeatureError.Text= "All features are currently associated to this product." 
    Else
        FeatureError.Text= "" 
        FeatureError.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I used display:none instead of the visible=false but the space is still there.

Comment: @jlg please give me some background regarding `dsNewFeatures` where does that come from? if `ds` stands for `DataSet` you shouldn't be comparing with `DBNull.Value` but rather with `Nothing`

Comment: @jlg never mind. I saw it on your markup. It's the DataSourceID which I assume is eiher SQLDataSource or something similar. Again, you have to compare to `Nothing`, not `DBNull.Value`. `DBNull.Value` is for comparing a particular value in a row of the result set, not for comparing against the datasource itself. Besides, dsNewFeatures is likely not null (Not Nothing in VB.NET) either regardless of whether there's data or not. You need to issue another select statement against the table in the database and count whether there are rows for the particular item or not and display FeatureError

Comment: I posted the datasource in the original post. I will change DBNull.Value to Nothing

Comment: @jlg it won't work. As I said above, dsNewFeatures won't be Nothing either. I will Update my answer with more pointers to see if that works. I'm not sure I understand exactly what's going on but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I added an image of the modal I am talking about. The space is at the bottom where the label is. When a user clicks on the remaining checkboxes in that modal, the error should pop up the next time the modal comes up. That way they know that there are no more features that can be added to that product.

Comment: It looks like the only way I can get that label to hide is if I put the Visible="false" right in the aspx page and not in the codebehind. I tried your update and added the rest of the checkboxes to the product to see if the message would unhide, but it stayed hidden.

Comment: @jlg it stayed hidden probably because now you set the Visible property to false by default. Check my second update in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @jlg check my second update. I don't know if the syntax is accurate but the idea is to set the Label visibility to true if there weren't any Items in the checkbox list (that's why I check if Items.Count==0).

Comment: it says "Expression expected" in the cbxAddFeature.Items.Count == 0 line. VB doesn't like == but I never remember what to change it to

Comment: oh haha I just deleted one of the =, but it still isn't working. I readded one of the checkboxes into the modal and the message is sitting right underneath the checkbox, still visible.

Comment: do you want me to keep the FeatureError.Visible in the other part of the vb code too? (from the 2nd update)

Comment: @jlg Yes, leave it. It won't matter.

Comment: I posted a picture of how it looks right now. The label still won't go away. Do you think I should put the code in that featurebutton_click sub? I'm confused now haha

Comment: @jlg I see. That's because the DataBinding is happening after the button is clicked; therefore, `(Items.Count=0)` always returns true. Will post another update.

Comment: @jlg I haven't forgotten about this. I got busy of all of a sudden. My idea is to implement OnDataBound on the CheckboxList and make sure in there that there's actually data to bind to to decide whether the visible property of the label should be true or false. I will try to post some code later today. You can read OnDataBound on MSDN and try it yourself in the mean time. See this question for now:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458390/databound-checkboxlist

Comment: Would it be possible to add a check to the sql in this `Protected Sub dsNewFeatures_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles dsNewFeatures.Selecting` I just double clicked on the datasource and that came up so I thought maybe and if else statement could be written here to unhide the label.

Comment: @jlg close, but not quite, the selecting event fires BEFORE the data is fetched; instead, add a handler for OnSelected and check whether e.AffectedRows>0 to determine the label visibility. I am connected from my cell now, but check sample here all the way at the bottom: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t115802-how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-the-dataset-the-record-count-delivered-by-a-sqldatasource.html

Comment: I edited the original post, the label itself is not set to visible=false. The label is still hidden though. I feel like I'm getting closer, but I still have something wrong.

Comment: Well it's a good thing you don't have to give up! Coz it works now :))))))))))))))))))))))))))) That is so awesome! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting white space because of how asp.net controls visibility behind the scenes.  When the control is rendered to the browser it's css style is set to `visibility: hidden` which will leave white space in the document where the element should be.  If you want to remove the  white space then you must use the css style `display: none`.

So, in your code:
Change

```
<asp:Label ID="FeatureError" runat="server" 
       Text="All features are currently associated to this product." 
       Display="none"></asp:Label>
```

To

```
<asp:Label ID="FeatureError" runat="server" 
       Text="All features are currently associated to this product."></asp:Label>
```

Change

```
For Each feature As ListItem In cbxAddFeature.Items
**FeatureError.Visible = False**
....
```

To

```
 For Each feature As ListItem In cbxAddFeature.Items
    FeatureError.Attributes.Add("Style", "Display: None;")
...
```

Change

```
**If (dsNewFeatures) == DBNull.Value Then
  FeatureError.Visible = True
End If**
```

To

```
Dim dv as DataView
dv = CType(dsNewFeatures.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
If(dv.Count == 0)
  FeatureError.Attributes("Style") = "Display: Inline;"
End If
```

You could also refactor the styles to be in a stylesheet if you wanted.

Reference: 
[Visibility vs Display in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: The line `If (dsNewFeatures) == DBNull.Value Then` doesn't work right. It says "expression expected" and has a squiggly line under one of the =, when I try to delete one the entire line gets a squiggly line.

Comment: I see what you mean, updated my answer.  You will have to check for an empty data set in another manner than what you were trying to do.

Comment: Good idea, but the label was still there.

Comment: do you think that what I am trying to accomplish could be done in Javascript? I've read that problems like this can be done in another way but I am even more new to Javascript than VB.net